# How to write deferred join in Cakephp 3.x?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I want this query.

```
SELECT Films.id AS `Films__id`, Films.name AS `Films__name` 
FROM films Films 
INNER JOIN (SELECT id FROM films ORDER BY released DESC LIMIT 10 OFFSET 100) AS Films2 ON Films.id = Films2.id 
ORDER BY Films.released DESC
```

This is what I have tried so far.

```
    $subquery = $this->find()->select(['id']);
    $query = $this->find()
        ->innerJoin(['Films2' => $subquery], ['Films.id = Films2.id'])
        ->order(['released' => 'DESC']);
```

This produces the following query which gives error because of the `Films` alias in the subquery. I have no idea how to change that alias.

```
SELECT Films.id AS `Films__id`, Films.name AS `Films__name` 
FROM films Films 
INNER JOIN (SELECT Films.id AS `Films__id` FROM films Films) Films2 ON Films.id = Films2.id 
ORDER BY Films.released DESC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to alias the returned column from the subquery. Since your condition is `Films.id = Films2.id` you need to return a column that is aliased as `id` inside the subquery. This is how:

```
$subquery = $this->find()->select(['id' => 'id']); // Avoid automatic aliasing
$query = $this->find()
    ->innerJoin(['Films2' => $subquery], ['Films.id = Films2.id'])
    ->order(['released' => 'DESC']);
```

Comment: this produces this query `SELECT Films.id AS `Films__id`, Films.name AS `Films__name` 
FROM films Films 
INNER JOIN (SELECT id AS `id` FROM films AS Films) AS Films2 ON Films.id = Films2.id 
ORDER BY Films.released DESC`. Will the alias in the subquery cause any problem? If so, how to remove or change it as well?